# Magento getStoreCategories() returns null

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have created categories in the back end of Magento. Doing a var_dump on either

`Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()`

or

`$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();`

Returns an empty set. If I look at each `$storeCategories` in a `foreach` loop, `category->children_count` returns an integer. However, '`all_children` and `children` both show `null`.

I can't build a menu if I don't have any categories! What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Categories **must** be children of "Default Category." This wasn't written down anywhere, but is what fixed hours  of lost time.

Under `Manage Catalog > Categories`, drag all existing categories to be subcategories of `Default`.